# Quill List Blank

Tags: javascript, css, menu, quill

I'm using the version of Quill from the CDN; I have Quill.js and Quill.snow.css defined.  I'm adding

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor', {
           modules: {
              toolbar: [
                 ['list'..]
              ]
           },
           theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
        });
```

When it renders it generates this:

```
<button class="ql-list" type="button"></button>
```

But I don't see anything although I can click in the space and trigger the action that way.

[image: Quill List Icon Not Showing]

I looked in the CSS and didn't find the `.ql-list` CSS class.  Obvious why it isn't working but why is the CSS file incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation here - https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/ The list should have a value as well. try and pass it as an object like -

`{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }` instead of `'list'`

And then the generated code might look like -

```
<button class="ql-list" type="button" value="ordered"></button>
```

And maybe in the CSS file you'll find something related to

```
.ql-list[value="ordered"]{
 // Styling for ordered list here
}
```

And if not in the CSS, it might be an SVG constructed dynamically based on the value. Who knows what people are upto these days!